# Text overflow in CSS columns

Tags: list, css

Suppose we have an `<ol>` or `<ul>` list with multiple CSS3 columns (the ones with the `-(vendor)-column` property or its sub-properties). If the last `<li>` in a column is too high, its content overflows to the next column ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/9MQba/2/)). How do you stop it from overflowing? I have tried

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and

```css
li {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

but they hide the numbers shown left to each `<li>` (the `list-style-type`).

Thanks!

Comment: You can set a height on your ol element, `<ol style="min-height: 100px;">`.. But I guess you are after the, oh so famous, "nobrcolumnplz" style so you don't have to set an explicit height?

Comment: I could use some JS, but indeed I prefer a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [the `column-fill` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#cf) (a property, by the way, which at present apparently [no browsers support](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-fill.asp)) states is automatically "balanced" (in height) if possible. Thus, there is no easy way to tell it otherwise.

Basically, to get what you want, you have to "balance" the number of rows for each column, which [gets ugly with extra `<br/>` tags](http://jsfiddle.net/9MQba/16/), or requires you [to set some bottom margin on the second item](http://jsfiddle.net/9MQba/18/) to force the balance.